# binary executable working in centos but not in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, centos, weblogic, executable, binary

I was trying to install weblogic 9 to test if an application is working correctly when migrated from a previous release. I downloaded the "Oracle WebLogic Server 9.2 MP3" and I was able to install it normally in CentOS 5.5

```
[jason@centos5]$ uname
Linux 2.6.34.1 #1 SMP Thu Jul 22 18:04:40 UTC 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[jason@centos5]$ cat /etc/*-release
CentOS release 5.5 (Final)
[jason@centos5]$ ls -l
total 655016
-r-xr-xr-x 1 jason jason 670070863 Aug 20 08:13 server923_linux32.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 jason jason        56 Aug 20 08:13 server923_linux32.bin.md5
[jason@centos5]$ cat server923_linux32.bin.md5
003046001d018e2981f0c91f5b6be9f6  server923_linux32.bin
[jason@centos5]$ md5sum -c server923_linux32.bin.md5
server923_linux32.bin: OK
[jason@centos5]$ file server923_linux32.bin
server923_linux32.bin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, stripped
[jason@centos5]$ ./server923_linux32.bin
Extracting 0%...................^C
[jason@centos5]$
```

but, when I tried the same in Ubuntu 10.04 it failed

```
[jason@ubuntu]$ uname
Linux 2.6.33.5 #2 SMP Thu Jun 10 15:26:23 UTC 2010 x86_64 unknown unknown GNU/Linux
[jason@ubuntu]$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04 LTS"
[jason@ubuntu]$ ls -l
total 1381736
-r-xr-xr-x 1 jason jason 670070863 Aug 20 22:00 server923_linux32.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 jason jason        56 Aug 20 22:00 server923_linux32.bin.md5
[jason@ubuntu]$ cat server923_linux32.bin.md5
003046001d018e2981f0c91f5b6be9f6  server923_linux32.bin
[jason@ubuntu]$ md5sum -c server923_linux32.bin.md5
server923_linux32.bin: OK
[jason@ubuntu]$ file server923_linux32.bin
server923_linux32.bin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, stripped
[jason@ubuntu]$ ./server923_linux32.bin
-bash: ./server923_linux32.bin: No such file or directory
[jason@ubuntu]$
```

I'm stumped any clues?

Comment: "No such file or directory" on an executable you know is there => run 'ldd' on it and it'll tell you what's missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 32-bit libraries aren't installed under Ubuntu. Use `ldd` to verify.

Comment: I guess you believe that he is running a x64 system.  If that is the case then he might need to install `ia32-libs` package.

Comment: @Zoredache: See the first command run in each session. And I know that most RH-derivatives install the 32-bit libs by default on x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ignacio, that was the problem

```
[jason@centos]$ ldd server923_linux32.bin
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x4a457000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x4a439000)
[jason@centos]$
```

I installed the 32-bit libs and now I'm able to run it :)

```
[jason@ubuntu]$ ldd server923_linux32.bin
        not a dynamic executable
[jason@ubuntu]$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
....
[jason@ubuntu]$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
[jason@ubuntu]$ ldd server923_linux32.bin
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf758b000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76f4000)
[jason@ubuntu]$ ./server923_linux32.bin
Extracting 0%.........^C
[jason@ubuntu]$
```